# Spring MVC 3 Binding of Complex Objects to the controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

Suppose i have two classes as shown below

```
Class Student{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
}

Class University{
   private String id;     
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private ArrayList<Student> students;
   //Getters and Setter methods
}
```

Now how can i bind university bean to form such that i can capture the data of student list in the controller ? Something like this

```
<form:form action ="controller.htm">
//... input tags binded with university id, name and address

<form:input path = "students[0].id">
<form:input path = "students[0].name">
<form:input path = "students[0].address">


<form:input path = "students[1].id">
<form:input path = "students[1].name">
<form:input path = "students[1].address">

//... and so on
</form:form>
```

Comment: That is how you do it.  You use the index subscript format, followed by the normal dot notation.  This also works with Maps, too, you just use the key instead of the number.  What the Spring JSTL form tag generates is an input with the name the same as the path, but the id the same minus the '[' and ']'.  The only thing you can't do, at least not easily, is have nested Collections.

Comment: So my question is the answer itself is it ? :o

Comment: How can iterate over the student collection ?

Comment: You can iterate using JSTL c:foreach.  You question was on how to bind a form value to a list, not how to iterate over the list.

Comment: You want to do both of what?  You bind to the form using a subscript, you loop using a c:forEach.  Use the index of the c:forEach in your subscript...done.  One thing I see missing above is you are not setting a modelAttribute to bind your form too.

Comment: Yes exactly that will be the solution. But how do i get index of c:forEach ??

Comment: Read the JSTL documentation for c:forEach, which describes all the attributes.  In particular varStatus, which keeps the running index:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html

Answer (score -1):

Example to iterate over the student collection.

```
 <tr>
        <td>Favourite Web Frameworks :</td>
        <td><c:forEach items="${studentCollection}" var="student">
               [<c:out value="${student.id}" />]
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Refer this [Example.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/)

Comment: Instead of just printing them i need them to be binded to another bean. How can i do that  ??